# Count number of elements per decile

Tags: mysql

I have a table that's something like this:

```
Name | Frequency
----------------
Bill |  12
Joe  |  23
Hank |  1
Stew |  98
```

I need to figure out how many people make up each decile of total frequency. I.e. if total `sum(frequency)` is 10,000 then each decile will have size 1,000. I need to know how many people make up each 1000. Right now I have done:

```
with rankedTable as (select * from TABLE order by frequency desc limit XXXX)
select sum(frequency) from rankedTable
```

And I am changing the XXXX so that the `sum(frequency)` adds up to decile values (which I know from `sum(frequency)/10`). There has to be a faster way of doing this.

Comment: Calculating the decile bit sounds ok. However, _I need to know how many people make up each 1000_  - could you elaborate a bit more on this (maybe with an example) please? How do you count the number of people in each 1000? What should the output look like?

Comment: The output should look like: 0-10: 1000, 10-20: 650, ... 90-100: 5 (so the top decile just 5 people whose frequency sums to 1000 while the bottom decile was 1000 people with frequency = 1 each)

Comment: Thanks for the additional info. I get a feeling that this could turn out to be one terribly complex query. How does one ensure that sum of frequencies for each of those ten sub-groups is exactly equal to the decile limit? If the exact sum is not a constraint, then should the preceding / succeeding sub-group(s) account for the underflow / overflow? If they should, what about the first and last sub-groups? If they shouldn't, then the results could turn out to be approximate (if not inaccurate). Also, could there be any sub-groups with no people in it - again, how does one really determine that?

Comment: Why not group by the INT(count / 1000)? You could use floor and ceiling to get the ends of the ranges.

Comment: I need the deciles to be defined by sum/1000 and then get the count for each of those deciles. Is that possible using a group by?

Answer (score 1):

I think this can give the n-percentile a user belongs to. I use variables for readability, but they are not strictly necessary.

```
set @sum := (select sum(freq) from t);
set @n := 10; -- define the N in N-perentile

select b.name, b.freq, sum(a.freq) as cumulative_sum, floor(sum(a.freq) / @sum * @n) as percentile
from t a join t b on b.freq >= a.freq
group by b.name
```

From this it is easy to count the members of each percentile:

```
select percentile, count(*) as `count`
from 
(
    select b.name, b.freq, sum(a.freq) as cumulative_sum, floor(sum(a.freq) / @sum * @n) as percentile
    from t a join t b on b.freq >= a.freq
    group by b.name
) x
group by percentile;
```

I hope this helps!